# Pyspark computing time not uniform across

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a scenario where computing seem to be not distributed uniformly as can be seen in the event timeline of a stage where must computing seem to be in a single executor (and the job have mainly an active task)

[image]

I already tried

```
main_df.repartition(num_executors*number_of_cores)
```

However behavior still seem as all processing is done in a single executor instead of uniformly distributed ,how can i tune or what are the best practices for finding how to repartition  so that i can leverage parallelism better?

Comment: what is the code that you are executing? repartition works for most cases because it gets rid of data skew which causes non uniform distribution. your code could give us a hint.. like are u using window functions without partitionBy clause?

Comment: It's a big script and i can't post all the code here, but, yes i am using Window functions but they do have partitionBy ,i will take a close look before and after the window functions.

Comment: I tracked this and it's not related to window functions, it is there even before them, basically i have a query to multiple hive tables at the beginning of the script, and a simple count() after the query shows this not uniform distribution, i even tried repartition(column) and repartition (number_of_partitions) after the query with no luck, any  ideas ?

Comment: i see. .count() is an expensive shuffle op but it should still not bring everything to 1 executor. i think this could be a cluster config problem rather than a code problem. any change u could post the .explain() of query where u think its going wrong? and what cluster manager/config are you using?

Comment: also before u run that query, what is df.rdd.getNumPartitions returning?